# Inline if-else with conditional operator not working React

Tags: reactjs

I've been struggeling with this basic stuff for a while now, but I cant seem to get it to work.

I'm getting data from our backend and if there're any deliveries objects it will be displayed with this:

```
<Expandable>
  <ObjectDisplay
    key={id}
    parentDocumentId={id}
    schema={schema[this.props.schema.collectionName]}
    value={this.props.collection.documents[id]}
  />
</Expandable>
```

But if there is no deliveries I'd like to display a message like `there's no deliveries`. I can use `.length` and `!deliveries` (I get that), but it seems like my conditional isn't working:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.collection.ids.length) //Getting how many deliveries there are with their id
  return (
    <div>//Struggling with this:

      {!this.props.collection.ids && this.props.collection.ids.length < 1
        ? <p>No deliviers</p>
        : <div className="box">
            {this.props.collection.ids
              .filter(
                id =>
                  // note: this is only passed when in top level of document
                  this.props.collection.documents[id][
                    this.props.schema.foreignKey
                  ] === this.props.parentDocumentId
              )
              .map(id => {
                return (
                  <Expandable>
                    <ObjectDisplay
                      key={id}
                      parentDocumentId={id}
                      schema={schema[this.props.schema.collectionName]}
                      value={this.props.collection.documents[id]}
                    />
                  </Expandable>
                )
              })}
          </div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I bet my problem is super basic, but I just can't get it to work.. Help is much appreciated!!

Comment: what is the issue with current code, is it throwing any error?

Comment: haha hey again mate! No, there is no error which makes me mad. It always returns the else block. When I switched places on the `<p>`-tag and the other block of code it returns only `No deliveries`

Answer (score 1):

Change your && to ||. You want to render "no delivers" if you have no ids (first test) OR if your ids.length is < 1

Comment: Hello Milenko! The problem I have now is that my `<p>` is not showing up, even if the array is empty. Also I noticed that when I press on a user that has `9` deliveries and then presses on another user that has `0` deliveries the console always prints out `9`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems indeed to be with your condition.

```
!this.props.collection.ids && this.props.collection.ids.length < 1
```

- `!this.props.collection.ids` is only true when the array is falsy. However, an empty array is not falsy - it's truthy.
- `this.props.collection.ids.length < 1` is true when the array is empty.

Since you are doing `&&` you require the array to be falsy and empty at the same time, which can never happen.

---

So simply change the condition from `&&` to `||`  and it should work. In other words:

```
!this.props.collection.ids || this.props.collection.ids.length < 1
```

though I think this is prettier:

```
!this.props.collection.ids || !this.props.collection.ids.length
```

Comment: Hello Chris! Thanks for the detailed answer (+1 for that). The problem I have now is that my `<p>-tag` is not showing up, even if the array is empty. 

Also I noticed that when I press on a user that has `nine` deliveries and then presses on another user that has `zero` deliveries the console always prints out `9`.

Comment: @MartinNordström, not sure what the whole user and pressing means as I cannot see your full app. However, it sounds like your props aren't being updated when they should? Try mocking the array (use a local variable instead of this.props.xx) to see if you get the expected output with your conditions. If you do, check your this.props and see if it updates as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition throws an error. See here

```
!this.props.collection.ids && this.props.collection.ids.length < 1
                       ^ 
                      !false && undefined
```

Change your condition to

```
this.props.collection.ids && this.props.collection.ids.length > 1
```

and put your placeholder in the else block of your ternary.

Comment: I see! The good part now is that it doesn't only return one condition, but my p tag isn't showing up :/

Comment: @MartinNordström What did you change? Can you edit your post

Comment: I tried your condition. I've also noticed that in my console the `this.props.collection.ids.length` is always nine. When I press on a user that has NO deliveries the number in the console is always nine.

Comment: @MuratK. OP wants the condition to be true when there are no deliveries. This will return true for the opposite.